# Inline object literal with a variable property

Tags: javascript

Why does Javascript syntax not support inline object literals with a variable property?  For example:

```
const f = function (arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}

f({}['some key'] = 1) // 1
f({ 'some key' : 1})  // [object Object] { some key: 1 }
```

Is there another alternative other than the two steps?

```
var o = {}
o['some key'] = 1
f(o)
```

Thanks!

Comment: is there a problem with `var o = { 'some key' : 1}` ? if you mean property name contained in variable it's [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Comment: Correct, sorry that is not reflected in the example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why does Javascript syntax not support inline object literals with a variable property?

You seem to be asking about variable properties, yet your examples do not use variables. Specifically, this example will work just fine.

```
f({ 'some key' : 1})
```

However, if you actually did want to use a variable without first creating the object, ECMAScript 6 now allows this.

So if this is your variable:

```
var my_variable = 'some key';
```

You can now use square brackets around the property name in the object literal, and it will use the value of the expression you provide:

```
var o = {[my_variable]: 1};
```

The `o` object will have a property named `"some key"`. This only works in the implementations that support this syntax of course.